# Android ViewPager ImageScaling

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to develop viewpager based first time user intro to my application.  However the images for that is getting blurred on my imageview.  Tried many solutions but nothing worked me. Badly need help.
Find my code snippet

```
public void setImageInViewPager() {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), itemData,
                options);

        if (options.outWidth > 7000 || options.outHeight > 6000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 10;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 6000 || options.outHeight > 5500) {
            options.inSampleSize = 9;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 5000 || options.outHeight > 4000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
        }

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), itemData,
                options);
        if (myBitmap != null) {
            try {
                if (ivImage != null) {
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing is, that your if/else statement doesn´t work like you may want to. >6000 and >7000....if you have a picture that is >7000 it is automatically >6000, you don´t need to put both statements there. Also, in one case you are writing >6000 and the next else statement is >6000 too. so which one should your app take.....?

Comment: I think what you wanted to to is: <6000 || >5000 so it is between 5000 and 6000......

Comment: he is checking the height and widht, not the same value

Comment: Yes @Chol is right. Its with respect to height and width.